# dr.HasRow always comes False even if the query works fine in db

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have a code and it has OracleReader and it has dr.HasRows which always comes False but the same query gives me the result in db

```
 Public Function Getmydata() As String
      Dim sql As String
      Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
      Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object) 
      Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)

    Try

      If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
         conn.Open()
      End If

      sql = "select name, city, address, phone from Students" 

      Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
      Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

      If dr.HasRows Then

        Do While dr.Read()

         row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
         For c As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1 
             row.Add(dr.GetName(c), dr.GetValue(c)) 
         Next

        rows.Add(row)
      Loop
     End If

    Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows)
```

here as to you see `Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader` 
 this part  has  dr.HasRows and it comes False so i can't retrieve any row from table`
 Any help appriciated ..

Thanks

Comment: Why Java?, c++, c#, Asp.Net are tagged? removed unnecessary tags. Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Not sure why it would return `false`, but why do you even need it in the first place? `dr.Read()` will return false if there are no rows.

Comment: Does this program connect to same server? Check your ConnectionString of `conn` and your tnsnames.ora.

Comment: I am also doubt on that part ( connection string ) but it looks fine to me and other parts works fine in the same .vb file but this one get me false..

Comment: It is also actually common problem according to my researc on google but there is almost no tangible result .

Comment: I seriously doubt HasRows is broken.  Please show links that it is a common problem.  If you proof then file a bug report Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue

all i did  writing the query statements ( Select , From and where ) in upper case

Answer (score -2):

change your code to:

```
  If dr.HasRows Then
   row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
   Do While dr.Read()      
     For c As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1 
         row.Add(dr.GetName(c), dr.GetValue(c)) 
     Next

    rows.Add(row)
   Loop
 End If
```

i.e: put the following line outside the loop

```
   row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

Comment: it is not even go that far. it gves the problem at oraclereader dr

Comment: Sorry, I answered you while "on the go" I thought your problem is the dictionary does not fill with rows.
Do you have any non-unicode charcters? do you get any error? are you sure you are connecting to the correct server?
Could you try: select * from tab